# Data Binding in .NET with CSLA BOs

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, csla

OK, I am having quite an issue with data bindings in .NET.
Some background information, my business object tier is using CSLA v1.0.
And _clientObj is passed in as a parameter as a business object that inherits CSLA.BusinessBase

Here is the code segment:

```
Dim nextClient As New ComboBox With { _
            .Name = "txtClientAtt" & (ClientBoxes.Count + 1).ToString(), _
            .DisplayMember = "FullNameAndID", .ValueMember = "ClientID", _
            .Tag = _clientObj}
nextClient.DataSource = ClientList.GetClientList(SelectedSite)


nextClient.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _clientObj, "ClientID")
If Not _clientObj.ClientID = Nothing AndAlso nextClient.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
     Debug.Print("How could I ever be inside this conditional????")
End If
```

That debug statement does indeed get reached if _clientObj is a pre-existing object with an assigned ID value.  How is that possible?  I was assuming that adding the data binding should immediately set the .SelectedValue property of the ComboBox if the DataSource object has an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not _clientObj.ClientID = Nothing
```

is not the correct way to test for a null value.  You should be using:

```
If Not _clientObj.ClientID Is Nothing
```

However, I'm not sure if that is actually the issue you are having or not.